# Tube surfaces, frenet frame and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, differential-geometry, frenet-frame

Given a curve $c:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and defining a surface $S:[a,b] \times [0,2 \pi]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ where

$S(s,t)=c(s)+R\cdot sin(t)\, N(s)+R\cdot cos(t)\, B(s)$

with being $N(s)$ and $B(s)$ the normal and binormal vectors of the curve $c$. And $r$ is the radius of the tube along $c$.

Now, I want to find a change of basis from the Cartesian to the orthonormal basis $F(s)$ (defined by the frenet frame) at every point of the curve $c(s)$ consisting of its tangent vector $T(s)$, the normal vector $N(s)$ and binormal vector $B(s)$.

If I construct the matrix $M_F^C$ for the change of basis from the Cartesian to the orthonormal basis of the curve $F(s)$ and apply this to the Surface, I will obtain the resulting vector $X(s,t)=(X_1,X_2,X_3):=M_F^C S(s,t)$. This vector should describe the surface of the tube for all $s\in[a,b]$ and satisfy 
${X_1}^2+{X_2}^2={R}^2$ $(*)$ (This is the actual result I am looking for).

When I calculate this for an exemplary curve I fail to meet $(*)$. I assume I am wrong somewhere about the change of basis. I have never dealt with these topics before and would appreciate some help.

---

I'll make an example:

Let's take the well known helix with Radius $r$ and being translated along the x-axis by $a$:

$c(s)=(r \,sin(\frac{s}{k})+a, r\, cos(\frac{s}{k}), h\, \frac{s}{k})$

with $k=\sqrt{h^2+r^2}$ the curve $c(s)$ is defined by its arc length  $s$. The frenet frame is given by

$T(s)= (\frac{r}{k}\, cos(\frac{s}{k}),-\frac{r}{k}\, sin(\frac{s}{k}),\frac{h}{k})$

$B(s)=(-\frac{h}{k}\, cos(\frac{s}{k}),\frac{h}{k}\, sin(\frac{s}{k}),\frac{r}{k})$

$N(s)=(-sin(\frac{s}{k}),-cos(\frac{s}{k}),0)$

Then the surface of my tube with radius $R$ will be defined as

$S(s,t)=c(s)+R\, cos(2 \pi t) \,B(s)+R\, sin(2\pi t)\,N(s)$

That's right this far, isn't is? Now, I define the change of basis $M=(T(s), B(s), N(s))$ with $T(s)$, $N(s)$, $B(s)$ as column vectors and define its inverse for the transformation. Simplified it yields

$M^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{r}{k}\, cos(\frac{s}{k})&-\frac{r}{k}\, sin(\frac{s}{k})&\frac{h}{k}\\
-\frac{h}{k}\, cos(\frac{s}{k})&\frac{h}{k}\, sin(\frac{s}{k})&\frac{r}{k})\\
-sin(\frac{s}{k})&-cos(\frac{s}{k})&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Which turns out to be the rows of the frenet frame $T(s)$, $N(s)$, $B(s)$.
The transformed curve results in

$M^{-1} S(s,t)=(\frac{h^2s+a\, r\,k \,cos(\frac{s}{k})}{k^2},\frac{h\,r\,s - a\, h\,k\, cos(\frac{s}{k})}{k^2}+R\,cos(2\pi t),-r+ R\, sin(2\pi t)-a\,sin(\frac{s}{k}))$

With $R$ being the radius of the tube, the root of the sum of the squared first and second argument should result in $R$. At least this is what I imagine should happen when I change my basis to the frenet frame of the curve. But when I do the math, it does not turn out to be right:

$\sqrt{{\left(\frac{h^2s+a\, r\,k \,cos(\frac{s}{k})}{k^2}\right)}^2+{\left(\frac{h\,r\,s - a\, h\,k\, cos(\frac{s}{k})}{k^2}+R\,cos(2\pi t)\right)}^2}\neq R$

Comment: You've made this sound very confusing. The change of basis matrix you're discussing is just the matrix whose columns are, say, $N(s), B(s), T(s)$. I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, however.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, this is what I thought. But then: When I apply the transformation to an arbitrary point $X$ at the defined surface, the components of this vector should satisfy ${X_1}^2+{X_2}^2=r^2$ ($r$ the radius of the tube surface). Or is this the wrong assumption?

Comment: That's right, but remember that coordinates transform by the inverse of the change of basis matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin hey, I edited the post with an example of my problem. Did the transformation as you described, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: First, you have a typo in $c(s)$. The third coordinate should be $hs/k$. Second, yes, $M^{-1}=M^\top$ because $M$ is an orthogonal matrix. Last, as I said in my original comment, if you want to get $X_1^2+X_2^2=r^2$, you need to start with $N$ and $B$ in the first two slots. the change of basis applies only in the tangent space at a particular point of $\Bbb R^3$ — it's not going to unwind all the translations you have going on here. So you should not have $c(s)$ in the formula for $S(s,t)$ when you apply the change of basis computation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hey, thank you. I corrected the typo and see what you mean by the order of the vectors in the matrix - that makes sense. But I am not entirely sure what you mean, that I should leave out $c(s)$ out of the formula for $S(s,t)$. Could you specify that? Do you mean that I should chose a certain point $s$ along the curve? You also said, that the change of basis applies only in the tangent space. What would I need to do if I wanted a change of basis to the tube at every point?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can make a change of basis in the $\Bbb R^3$ *with its origin at $c(s)$* that varies smoothly with $s$. You're basically rotating your basis for $\Bbb R^3$ as you move along the curve, but the origin moves along with you. There's no way to get anything nice incorporating the coordinates of $c(s)$ itself.